# Copy selective data from master sheet to another on addition of a row to master sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a master sheet that populates using a form.
Now I want to copy content from column 0,6,9,10,15 to a different spreadsheet.
So, far i have the following code -

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.openById("1o8_hOUvPG254AFm61lz9Qn1_HwxMUSI-WM");
  var sht=ss.getSheetByName('Clientsheet');
  var rng=sht.getDataRange();
  var rngA=rng.getValues();
  var row=rngA[rngA.length-1];
  var stock=SpreadsheetApp.openById("1N-2BN3-4HHdpMWso58ndJGGaEugWCaP6fleT4");
  var ssht=stock.getSheetByName('Outward Details');
  var lstrow= ssht.getLastRow();
  var nxtrow= lstrow+1;
  ssht.getRange('nxtrow, 1').setValue(row[0]); //date
  ssht.getRange('nxtrow, 2').setValue("Module");
  ssht.getRange('nxtrow, 3').setValue(row[6]);
ssht.getRange('nxtrow +1, 1').setValue(row[9]);
ssht.getRange('nxtrow +1, 2').setValue(row[10]);
ssht.getRange('nxtrow +1, 3').setValue(row[15]);
 SpreadsheetApp.flush();
}
```

This code produces a Range not found error on Line 11.
Please help me understand where I'm going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use `ssht.getRange('nxtrow, 1').setValue(row[0]);` because `nxtrow` is a variable, but you're passing it as a String. Use this instead:

```
ssht.getRange(nxtrow, '1').setValue(row[0]);
```